# How to return a Record of corresponding (by index) narrow types extracted from an array in TS

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm in a situation that could be summed up with the following example:

```
interface Config {
     readonly key: string,
     readonly config: number,
}

// narrow typed array
const arr = [{key:"hi", config:34}, {key:"hello", config:75}] as const;

function fn<T extends ReadonlyArray<Config>>(configs: T) {

    type ks = T[number]['key'];
    type cs = T[number]['config'];

    return {} as {
        [K in ks]: cs
    }
}

const res = fn(arr);
```

I need `{hi:34, hello:75}` as return type, but currently the type of `res` is `{hi:34|75, hello:34|75}`. I don't know what other type operations I should perform on `cs` to get what I need, nor if using `cs` is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user extract to get the item in the union of tuple items corresponding to the current key:

```
interface Config {
    readonly key: string,
    readonly config: number,
}

// narrow typed array
const arr = [{key:"hi", config:34}, {key:"hello", config:75}] as const;

function fn<T extends ReadonlyArray<Config>>(configs: T) {

    type ks = T[number]['key'];
    type cs = T[number];

    return {} as {
        [K in ks]: Extract<cs, {key: K}>['config']
    }
}

const res = fn(arr); // { hi: 34; hello: 75; }
```